# Deploying multiple CloudFormation stacks from a single serverless.yml template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

When I do an `sls deploy`, I ended up with a CloudFormation stack named `<name of service>-<stage>`.

I would like to deploy multiple CloudFormation stacks using the same template.  One way this could work is based on an environment variable.  Something like:

`SOURCE=twitter sls deploy`

...would yield a cloud formation stack named `<name of service>-<SOURCE env var>-<stage>`, which in this case would be `scrape-twitter-prod`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#referencing-environment-variables) you can reference environment variables with `${env:VARIABLE}`. You can then do something like:

```
service: scrape-${env:SOURCE}
```